# How to add JSENCODE script to a javascript Onclick function?

Tags: visualforce

I want to add JSENCODE to my visualforce page where I have a javascript function and it is used in one of my statements in the code. Below is my code:

```
<a style="padding-left:5px;color:black;" id="link" href="javascript:void(0);" 
   onclick ="changeStage('{!Values.Stage_Value__c}');">{!Values.Stage_Value__c}</a>
```

And here is my Javascript Function code:

```
function changeStage(changeStageName) {

    stagename(changeStageName);
 }
```

Can Somebody help me in solving this!! Any help or suggestion is appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

This will avoid e.g. embedded quotes in `Stage_Value__c` breaking the JavaScript:

```
onclick="changeStage('{! JSENCODE(Values.Stage_Value__c) }');"
```